# Unable to edit Okhttp idle connection pool 5 minutes default timing

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, okhttp

Im running okHttp with the following jar okhttp-4.2.2. I am calling a REST post call to my client side but im encountering a connection reset each time the call exceeds 5 minutes.
I have adjusted the timeout to 900 seconds, increased the connection pool timeout to 10 minutes but it is still failing.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                             builder.connectTimeout(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                             builder.readTimeout(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                             builder.writeTimeout(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                             builder.callTimeout(900, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                             builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(false);
                             builder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));

 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
              httpClient = builder.build();

 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonString, MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"));

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(applicationPath)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+jsonStringAuth.getString("access_token"))
                .header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

This is the stack trace.

```
2022-11-09 09:30:37,411 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819) java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2022-11-09 09:30:37,411 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,412 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,412 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,412 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,413 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,413 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,414 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,414 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okio.InputStreamSource.read(Okio.kt:102)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,415 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:159)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,415 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:349)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,416 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:222)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,416 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:210)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,416 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:181)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,417 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:105)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,417 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:82)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,417 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,418 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:37)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,418 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,418 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,419 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,419 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,419 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,420 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,420 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,420 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,421 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,421 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,421 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
2022-11-09 09:30:37,422 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11819)     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to reproduce this problem with a more recent version of WildFly (e.g. 26.1.x)?  As a workaround, try switching the relevant cache configuration from the Infinispan subsystem to use a non-transactional cache.

Comment: I just edited my post. I added some additional logging and found out the root cause was my post calls will get a connection reset each time it exceeds 5 minutes.